# How to get second index values of array elements according first index in postgresql9.4?

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql-9.4

I have table called arraytable -> `create table arraytable(id int, somearray int[][])`

```
INSERT INTO arraytable(id, somearray) values(1,array[[3,5],[4,12]]);
INSERT INTO arraytable(id, somearray) values(2,array[[7,15],[13,47],[15,27],[18,97]]);
INSERT INTO arraytable(id, somearray) values(3,array[[56,1],[67,78],[105,78]]);
```

I have no idea how to select second index values of array elements in all rows according to particular first index values of array elements;

First, I want to select 6 array elements that have first index values smaller than 67 which would look like:

```
[4,12],[7,15],[13,47],[15,27],[18,97],[56,1]
```

And now I need to select second index values of these which would look like:

```
12, 15, 47, 27, 97, 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so ugly I'm sure there is a better way to do this but since nobody has answered this question, I'll post this answer bearing in mind that I don't think it's a good solution and a stable one. Don't use this in production! It's merely an exercise for me with my very limited knowledge about how multidimensional arrays work in Postgres.

It's just for the sake of answering:

```
with x as (
  select foo.id, goo.nr, goo.first_ind, foo.somearray 
  from (
    select *, somearray[1:array_upper(somearray,1)][1] AS first_indexes 
    from arraytable
  ) foo, 
  unnest(foo.first_indexes) WITH ORDINALITY goo(first_ind,nr) 
  where goo.first_ind < 67
) 
select string_agg(z.second_ind::text, ', ' order by x.id, x.nr) 
from x 
join (
  select * 
  from (
    select id, first_ind, somearray[1:array_upper(somearray,1)][2:3] AS second_indexes 
    -- [2:3] should actually be [2] but for some reason it wouldn't work? so this is specific to data with 2 indexes
    from x
  ) y, 
  unnest(y.second_indexes) WITH ORDINALITY goo(second_ind,nr)
) z on 
  x.id=z.id 
  and x.nr=z.nr 
  and x.first_ind=z.first_ind;
```

Output:

```
     string_agg
--------------------
5, 12, 15, 47, 27, 97, 1
(1 row)
```

Also, `{3,5}` should be taken into consideration so `5` should be present in the output.

Comment: Hoping for someone to provide a better answer to learn from as I barely had any experience with multidimensional arrays :-)